# "A variable index into the for generate block is illegal" error

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I created a group tasks using "generate" and was trying to call them using a for loop.

I have used generate block to create multiple instances of module, so I thought I could use it similarly to create multiple tasks. I plan to have no arguments for the tasks, and always call the tasks in a loop. But the number of tasks to be called is dependent on a parameter (instead of "4" in the example below, it will be a parameter).

Here is an example of what I was trying to do:

```
  task display;
    fork
      other_tasks();
      for(int i=0; i<4; i++) begin
        create_task[i].print_i;
      end
//      create_task[0].print_i;
//      create_task[1].print_i;
//      create_task[2].print_i;
//      create_task[3].print_i;
    join
  endtask

  generate
    for(genvar i=0; i<4; i++) begin : create_task
      task print_i();
        $display("%t, %m, Message #%0d", $time, i);
        #1;
      endtask
    end : create_task
  endgenerate
```

The code gives me no error if I call the tasks separately (commented lines) instead of using "for". However, I would prefer to do this using a loop because the number of tasks I need to call may vary. What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Please edit your question with the following information: What is the purpose of putting the task in the generate block in the first place? do you always plan to call the tasks in a loop? or sometimes select just a few of then? Do you plan to have any arguments to this task? If so, will they be the same values for all tasks?

Comment: @dave_59 Thank you for your comment. I have edited my question with more information.

Comment: Note. 'generate' blocks are evaluated statically before any dynamic action. Therefore, any dynamic `i` from your task cannot be used to access *static* naming generated by the loop. Therefore `create_task[0].print_i` has a chance to work (depending on the tool), while using `create_task[i].print_i` cannot work if `i` is a dynamic variable. But you might be able to do it from another *generate* block. In other words, do not try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the the limited requirements you provided, the simplest solution is  triggering a single event that calls all the tasks.

```
 event print;
 task display;
    fork
      other_tasks();
      ->print;
    join
  endtask

  generate
    for(genvar i=0; i<4; i++) begin : create_task
      task print_i();
        $display("%t, %m, Message #%0d", $time, i);
        #1;
      endtask
    always @print print_i;
    end : create_task
  endgenerate
```

If you want to only call some of the tasks, you could create an array of events, and trigger the array indexed by a variable.

```
 event print[4];
 task display;
    fork
      other_tasks();
      ->print[some_index];
    join
  endtask

  generate
    for(genvar i=0; i<4; i++) begin : create_task
      task print_i();
        $display("%t, %m, Message #%0d", $time, i);
        #1;
      endtask
    always @print[i] print_i;
    end : create_task
  endgenerate
```

If you ever need to pass arguments to the task, there are ways of using interface classes instead of using events.

```
interface class abstract_print;
  pure virtual task printer(input int arg);
endclass

abstract_print list[4];

 task display;
    fork
      other_tasks();
      list[some_index].print(some_arg);
    join
  endtask

  for(genvar i=0; i<4; i++) begin : create_task
      task print_i(int arg);
        $display("%t, %m, Message #%0d", $time, i);
        #1;
      endtask
    class concrete_print implements abstract_print;
       function new;
         list[i] = this;
       endfunction
       task print(int arg);
          print_i(arg);
       endtask
    endclass
    concrete_print p = new;
    
  end : create_task
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate loops are for structural design.
Move the loop inside the called task and use for.  Pass an arg to the task which determines the number of times to do something.

```
module tb ();
  
  task display;
    fork  
      other_tasks();
      
      for(int i=0; i<4; i++) begin
        print_i(3);
      end
      
    join
 endtask

  task other_tasks();
  endtask
  
  task print_i(input int i);
    for(int j = 0; j < i ; j++)
      $display("time = %0t, count = #%0d", $time, j);
    #1;
  endtask
  
  initial begin
    display();
  end
  
endmodule
```

Produces:

```
time = 0, count = #0
time = 0, count = #1
time = 0, count = #2
time = 1, count = #0
time = 1, count = #1
time = 1, count = #2
time = 2, count = #0
time = 2, count = #1
time = 2, count = #2
time = 3, count = #0
time = 3, count = #1
time = 3, count = #2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried your solution with some modifications. But it seems like the "fork ... join" has lost its functionality. I wanted to have each call of the task "print_i" starts in parallel at time = 0. I got the expected result by replacing the for loop in "display" with calling print_i(3) 4 times. But I would still like to use a loop to achieve this. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Referencing the code I modified for this post: If the #1 is removed from the print_i task, then all the tasks launched start at the same time ==0.

Comment: The generate loop is unrolled at t=0.  If you want more dynamic flexibility in testbench, then put the task in a class object,  Then multiple objects can be created in a loop at any time, and the objects methods can be run at any time.